# Error:System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need your help, When I type something in the text box, it sends me the following error: **"System.IndexOutOfRangeException"** and **Additional Information: "B.Nombre"** .
 I don't know what it could be, I'm looking for the error even try with parameters and nothing.
Thanks!

```
var strcn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConexionDB"].ToString();

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcn))
{
    con.Open();
    string commandString = @"SELECT  
           B.Nombre,G.Nombre,D.Nombre,B.Precio,G.Precio,D.Precio,
           B.Gramos,G.Gramos,D.Gramos,B.Tabletas,G.Tabletas,D.Tabletas
       FROM TblBenavides B INNER JOIN TblGuadalajara G ON B.Nombre = G.Nombre 
                           INNER JOIN TblDelAhorro D ON G.Nombre = D.Nombre 
       WHERE B.Nombre='" + TxtMedicamento.Text + "'" +
             "AND G.Nombre='" + TxtMedicamento.Text + 
             "' AND D.Nombre='" + TxtMedicamento.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, con);
    SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (myReader.Read())
    {
        label3.Text = myReader["B.Nombre"].ToString();
        label4.Text = myReader["G.Nombre"].ToString();
        label5.Text = myReader["D.Nombre"].ToString();
        this.label8.Text = myReader["B.Precio"].ToString();
        this.TxtGprecio.Text = myReader["G.Precio"].ToString();
        this.TxtDprecio.Text = myReader["D.Precio"].ToString();
        this.label6.Text = myReader["B.Gramos"].ToString();
        this.TxtGgramos.Text = myReader["G.Gramos"].ToString();
        this.TxtDgramos.Text = myReader["D.Gramos"].ToString();
        this.label7.Text = myReader["B.Tabletas"].ToString();
        this.TxtGtabletas.Text = myReader["G.Tabletas"].ToString();
        this.TxtDtabletas.Text = myReader["D.Tabletas"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: when you are getting data from reader, make sure you are using correct column name. "B.Nombre" does not exist in your dataset.
use aliases for column names.
change your select query 
SELECT B.Nombre as B_Nombre,G.Nombre as G_Nombre

Comment: After adding the column aliases (_B.Nombre as NombreB, ..._) please take a bit of your time to understand what is an Sql Injection and why your code is a disaster waiting to happen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`B.Nombre`,`G.Nombre`,`D.Nombre` all have the same column name because you don't specify aliases for them. The `B`,`G`,`D` prefixes are just the alias for the table-names but they are not part of the column-name. So you can't use `myReader["B.Nombre"]`(for example) because that column doesn't exist(that's the reason for the exception).

Instead use column aliases for those columns or the `int`-indexer with the index of the column.

```
SELECT B.Nombre As B_Nombre,G.Nombre As G_Nombre, D.Nombre As D_Nombre
...
```

and then you can use these names, f.e.:

```
 label3.Text = myReader["B_Nombre"].ToString();
```

You can also use the the `int`-indexer:

```
 label3.Text = myReader[0].ToString(); // first column in the select
```

---

Instead of concatenating strings to build your sql query you should [use parameterized queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/secure-data-access#parameterized-commands-and-sql-injection), f.e. to avoid sql-injection.

Answer (score 2):

You need to alias your column names.
So your query should be something like this for example:

```
var strcn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConexionDB"].ToString();

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcn))
{
    con.Open();
    string commandString = @"SELECT  
           B.Nombre as BNombre,G.Nombre as GNombre,D.Nombre as DNombre,B.Precio as BPrecio ,G.Precio as GPrecio,D.Precio as DPrecio,
           B.Gramos as BGramos,G.Gramos as GGramos,D.Gramos as DGramos,B.Tabletas as BTabletas,G.Tabletas as GTabletas,D.Tabletas as DTabletas
       FROM TblBenavides B INNER JOIN TblGuadalajara G ON B.Nombre = G.Nombre 
                           INNER JOIN TblDelAhorro D ON G.Nombre = D.Nombre 
       WHERE B.Nombre='" + TxtMedicamento.Text + "'" +
             "AND G.Nombre='" + TxtMedicamento.Text + 
             "' AND D.Nombre='" + TxtMedicamento.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, con);
    SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (myReader.Read())
    {
        label3.Text = myReader["BNombre"].ToString();
        label4.Text = myReader["GNombre"].ToString();
        label5.Text = myReader["DNombre"].ToString();
        this.label8.Text = myReader["BPrecio"].ToString();
        this.TxtGprecio.Text = myReader["GPrecio"].ToString();
        this.TxtDprecio.Text = myReader["DPrecio"].ToString();
        this.label6.Text = myReader["BGramos"].ToString();
        this.TxtGgramos.Text = myReader["GGramos"].ToString();
        this.TxtDgramos.Text = myReader["DGramos"].ToString();
        this.label7.Text = myReader["BTabletas"].ToString();
        this.TxtGtabletas.Text = myReader["GTabletas"].ToString();
        this.TxtDtabletas.Text = myReader["DTabletas"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, also pay attention to what others said in the comments and @TimSchmelter's excellent answer regarding sql injection. Concatenating directly from the UI is not recommended to say the least.